# Calling ruby module's method from java

Tags: ruby, jruby

Have a simple ruby module code like this in test.rb:

```
module Test
def self.update(a,b)
  "Hello world"+a+b
end
end
```

then I wrote java code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {

System.setProperty("org.jruby.embed.localvariable.behavior", "transient");
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("jruby");
Reader reader = new FileReader("/temp/test.rb");
Object receiver = engine.eval(reader);
System.out.println((engine.eval("Test::update")));
}
```

This code printed "Hello World" as expected but I tried various ways to pass the parameters to the method like:

```
SimpleBindings bindings = new SimpleBindings();
bindings.put("a", 1);
bindings.put("b", 2);
System.out.println((engine.eval("Test::update", bindings)));
```

I could not able to pass arguments, how do we pass arguments to a module's method from java?

UPDATE: The following approached worked:

```
System.out.println((engine.eval("Test::update(a,b)", bindings)));
```

Comment: UPDATE: the following approach worked: System.out.println((engine.eval("Test::update(a,b)", bindings)));

Comment: you can make your own answer.